# Measure 3D object (.USDZ) frame during animation in swift ARKit & RealityKit

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, realitykit, usdz

How can I accurately measure the width of a 3D object loaded in an ARView in Swift, especially when the object is animated and its width increases? I’ve tried using the following code snippets with RealityKit, but the printed measurements are incorrect.

```
 var anchorEnt = AnchorEntity(.face)

 func loadModel(into arView: ARView) {
     downloadUsdz.downloadModel(model: selectedModel, loadOnFace: {
         var cancellable: AnyCancellable? = nil
         cancellable = AnchorEntity.loadModelAsync(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: model.usdzPath))
             .sink(receiveCompletion: { [self] error in
                 cancellable?.cancel()
                 if(anchorEnt.children.isEmpty) {
                     loadModel(into: arView)
                 }
             }, receiveValue: { [self] entity in
                 entity.availableAnimations.forEach { animation in
                     entity.playAnimation(animation)
                 }
                 
                 Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true) { time in
                     let currentBounds = entity.visualBounds(relativeTo: self.anchorEnt)
                     
                     let currentWidth = currentBounds.max.x - currentBounds.min.x
                     let currentWidth2 = currentBounds.extents.x
                     
                     print("Current Width: \(currentWidth), \(currentWidth2)") // Both Prints same value
                 }
                 
                 retryModelLoading(entity: entity, arview: arView)
                 cancellable?.cancel()
             })
     })
 }
```